# После "обёртывания" в функцию перестало отрисовывать фигуру

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>  NEW </title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">Обновите браузер</canvas>

        <style>#canvas { background-color: rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2); }</style>


        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            var   ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');

                var side = 0;
                var up  = 0;

                function drawRect () {
                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
                //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
                ctx.fillRect (up, side, 25, 25);
                }

                //var gameLoop = function () {
                    drawRect ();
                  // side += 5
                //};

                //gameLoop();

         </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: уберите `var` перед `ctx`, или поменяйте `,` на `;` после `document.getElementById("canvas")`

Comment: @ Igor спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в `var`    перед `ctx`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  side = 0,
  up  = 0;

 function drawRect() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    ctx.fillRect (up, side, 25, 25);
}

drawRect()
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q97tebk/)